# What are the types of deadlocks?

Tags: multithreading, deadlock

as per title, what are the types of deadlocks? Recently I was asked this question, but I was aware of only on type of deadlock, when thread A is waiting for a lock which is acquired by thread B, whereas thread B is waiting for a lock which is acquired by thread A. Are there any other?

Comment: self-deadlock? tread A forgets it already locked a resource and tries to re-lock it?

Comment: Or thread A is waiting on a resource that thread B has locked, and thread B never releases it. The Wikipedia page might help you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock

Answer (score 8):

Two types of deadlocks can be considered:

**1. Resource Deadlock**

Occurs when processes are trying to get exclusive access to devices, files, locks, servers, or other resources.

In *Resource deadlock model*, a process waits until it has received all the resources that it has requested.

The resource model is also called the *AND model*. In this model, a deadlock occurs if and only if there is a cycle of waiting processes, each dependent on the next process in the cycle to make progress.

Possible situation: *Transaction-processing scenario*

**2. Communication Deadlock**

Also referred to as *Communication deadlock model*, occurs when process A is trying to send a message to process B, which is trying to send a message to process C which is trying to send a message to A.

The communication deadlock model is also called *OR model*.

Evidently, it easily satisfies the *Circular-wait condition* for deadlock to occur.

Possible situation: *Message-passing scenario*

Hope this will work for you and satisfy the questioner.